# How do I access photos from my iphone app?

Tags: objective-c, photos

Is there a way to easily access photos from your own iphone app using objective-c? Any tutorials would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you should read how to use UIImagePicker controller in iPhone SDK.