# import photos option in app

Tags: ios, photos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I access photos from my iphone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846534/how-do-i-access-photos-from-my-iphone-app)

I'm building an app that allows the user to import a photo currently on their phone. I noticed several other apps have this option (WhatsApp, Facebook come to mind). Is there an example how this is done?

I've searched for an API for this...and not finding it. I did however, find this: 
https://github.com/andreyvit/SoloComponents-iOS

It allows to show the photos, but how do we get the photos currently on the phone?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html

Comment: Wow, I was looking at google all over for this. If you put this below, I will accept the answer.

Comment: See my answer ...... Without third party tool you get photos from facebook http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the full documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html As a bonus, you can also take pictures with this class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) for doing this.

This is a simple [tutorial](http://idevhub.com/picking-images-with-the-iphone-sdk-uiimagepickercontroller/) which may help you. Also check this [link](http://blog.hanpo.tw/2012/01/uiimagepickercontroller-and-simple.html) for integrating the camera photos